# How to fuzzy search single sqlite3 field

Tags: search, sqlite, fuzzy-search

I have a bunch of rows in a basic CRUD app that I want to let the user search for by title. SQLite3 has a full-text search solution, but is it recommended to also use that for not-full-text searches, or is there a simpler way? For example, PostgreSQL has trigrams, which function really well for this simple use-case, and perhaps SQLite3 has something similar.

I feel like this question must have been answered before, but I cannot find such an answer, so I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTS is a good fit for this use-case. You can use the [`MATCH`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) operator on individual columns or the entire table. See https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: I didn't see any fuzzy-word type stuff in sqlite FTS3/4/5.  It sounds from the mention of trigrams like that's what the OP wanted (and so do I).  Is there support for fuzzy matching somewhere that I missed in there?

Comment: Not fuzzy search

Comment: I found your answer looking for "Fuzzy Logic Search" which used to be in ACCPAC Plus which was a b-trieve database. In your link it talks about FTS3 and FTS4. What FTS stand for isn't explained in the link. Is it "Fuzzy Table Search"?

Comment: FTS at least in the case of SQLite3 means "Full Text Search"

Answer (score 4):

The [Spellfix1](https://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html) virtual table can be used in cooperation with [FTS](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) to implement a fuzzy full text search in sqlite. This allows searching for potentially misspelled words, which (as far as I know) isn't supported by sqlite's FTS on its own.